# How can i get person class and segmentation from MSCOCO dataset?

Tags: dataset, image-segmentation, mscoco

I want to download only person class and binary segmentation from COCO dataset. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [pycocotools](https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools/) .

- import library

  ```py
  from pycocotools.coco import COCO
  ```
- load json file of coco annotation

  ```py
  coco = COCO('/home/office/cocoDataset/annotations/instances_train2017.json')
  ```
- get category IDs of coco dataset

  ```py
  category_ids = coco.getCatIds(catNms=['person'])
  ```
- get annotations of a single image

  ```py
  annotations = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=image_id, catIds=category_ids, iscrowd=False)
  ```
- here each person has different annotation, and i'th person's annotation is `annotation[i]` hence merge all the annotations and save it

  ```py
  if annotations:
    mask = coco.annToMask(annotations[0])
    for i in range(len(annotations)):
      mask |= coco.annToMask(annotations[i])
    mask = mask * 255
    im = Image.fromarray(mask)
    im.save('~/mask_name.png')
  ```